# Where to get example data used in PostgreSQL documentation?

Tags: postgresql

I would like to follow through and experiment with the examples in the PostgreSQL documentation but find it difficult to compare impacts of commands without actual working data.

Is there sample data or a default database that correlates with all the examples in the PostgreSQL documentation ?

**Problem:**

Getting table or column "does not exist" errors when executing SQL in documentation (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/tutorial-window.html):

```
SELECT depname, empno, salary, enroll_date
FROM
  (SELECT depname, empno, salary, enroll_date,
          rank() OVER (PARTITION BY depname ORDER BY salary DESC, empno) AS pos
     FROM empsalary
  ) AS ss
WHERE pos < 3;
```

**Error:**

```
SQL Error [42703]: ERROR: column "enroll_date" does not exist
```

**Attempted workarounds:**

- Stack Builder does not list sample data installation options
- The sources do not contain required sample data (eg. "src\tutorial" directory et al in https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/source/v10.23/postgresql-10.23.tar.gz)
- Any 3rd-party sample data found appear incomplete or non-official (eg. "advanced-psql-examples.sql" from https://gist.github.com/marko-asplund/5561404 missing "enroll_date" column)

**Versions:**

- PostgreSQL 10.23 (https://web3.pioneersoftware.co.uk/files/pgsql/10/postgresql-10.23-1-windows.exe)
- Stack Builder 4.2.1

Comment: I don't think there is any download location for the tables used in the examples.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but: Postgres 10 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: I can't find it listed in https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Sample_Databases so I presume there isn't any publicly available sample database with that structure. It reminds me of Oracle HR database, but I think tables are different.

Comment: For `empsalary` the DDL and data can be found in "src\test\regress\sql\window.sql" but there are other tables mentioned in the documentation that I cannot find accompanying the sources (eg. `regional_sales`, `top_regions`, `included_parts` etc) (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/queries-with.html). And of those that do have DDL (eg. `orders`, `products`) there is only minimal sample data (eg. 1 row) simply to satisfy a regression test. It is annoying to not be able to follow through the documentation with sufficient sample data. Oracle provides default sample data for this very reason.